# Backtransforming estimates of a linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-transformation, lme4-nlme

I would like to know if there is any way (perhaps a bootstrap approach) to backtransform the estimates of a linear mixed effects model with a transformed response variable (and transformed predictor variable).

Let’s say those are my data:

```
x = exp(rnorm(100, 5))
y = log(x)^2 + rnorm(100, 3)
random = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50))
dat = data.frame(y,x)
```

and this is the model I fit:

```
library(lme4)
mod = lmer(sqrt(y) ~ log2(x) + (1|random), dat) 
summary(mod)
```

Is there any way to show how

- y changes with x or how
- y changes with log2(x)

rather than how sqrt(y) changes with log2(x)?